# R markdown present equation coefficient result outside of chunks

Tags: r, pdf, equation, r-markdown

I need to present results of linear model in an equation in a pdf file.

My R markdown example is this:

```````
```{r}
D <- data.frame(x1=1:10,x2=cos(21:30),y=sin(1:10))
M1 <- lm( y ~ x1 + x2, data=D )
( C <- coef(M1) )
``````
```````

Which results

```
(Intercept)          x1          x2 
0.08505352 -0.02160815 -0.93696541
```

[image: from the pdf output]

Resulted in a string output, but not a graphic equation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with R markdown, but have you considered using knitR or sweave?

Answer (score 3):

You can use r code within the `$$` formula:

```
$$y = `r C[1]``r C[2]` x1 `r C[3]` x2 $$
```

Comment: Thank you @tospig, that is the answer! :) Now my code is: `$$ `r paste("y = ",C[1]," ", C[2],"x1 ",C[3],"x2 ",sep="")` $$`